# MySQL Advanced SUM function

Tags: mysql

### Good day!

I am sorry If this question was already asked, but I am kind of in hurry, so I am not sure.

### I have 2 tables:

*Table.Cars* and *Table.Price*

In table Cars:

```
ID Auto_Increment Primary key NOT NULL
Name VARCHAR(30)
```

In table Price:

```
CarsID Primary key NOT NULL
Units Int
Price_per_unit decimal(10,2)
Total decimal(10,2)
```

So, what I need to do is, Create column (TOTAL* (Name does not need to be necessary this one)), in table Price, Set it to do Mathematical function.

Basicly, I want Column.Total to show Units * price_per_unit which would be:

```
ALTER TABLE Price
ADD TOTAL Decimal(10,2)

UPDATE Price SET Total = SUM(Units * Price_per_unit);
```

Which will look like this:

```
---------------------------------------------------
| ID | Units | Price_per_unit |   Total   | TOTAL |
---------------------------------------------------
| 1  | 12    | 30000,00       | 360000,00 | NULL  |
| 2  | 5     | 12000,00       | 60000,00  | NULL  |
```

And here comes my problem. I want to make TOTAL, to look like this:

```
---------------------------------------------------------
| ID | Units | Price_per_unit |   Total   | TOTAL       |
---------------------------------------------------------
| 1  | 12    | 30000,00       | 360000,00 | 420000      |
| 2  | 5     | 12000,00       | 60000,00  |             |
|_______________________________________________________|
```

So, next time, I put new record in table Price, I need TOTAL, to auto SUM my table by taking data from Units * Price_pre_unit.

So my question is, how do I make this query?

Comment: SQL Server is a Microsoft database that's completely different to MySQL. It looks as though you've got a little confused and have used in in the sense of a database server - one that runs a RDBMS. I've removed the tag but if you are using both MySQL and SQL Server of course put it back in.

Comment: imo, just curious, is 'price per unit' : 1)  always supplied?  2) Sometimes supplied? Is `total price` 1) always supplied 2) sometimes calculated? Is 'units' 1) always supplied 2) sometimes calculated?  Please, imo, it is important. use some of these combinations and the accounts will like you. Others - not so much. i.e. 'total price' and `total units`. Always store those.

Comment: Sorry, I added tag accidentally.

Comment: Ryan, It will not be usable database in any way, it's just school test subject, to test, how good I know SET, UPDATE commands. As for columns, suplied are only 'price per unit' 'Units'. If this is what you asked. I am not that good at english, sorry :P

Comment: @Vairis, Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want Mysql database to do it automatically, it seems you are looking for a trigger. You should tun this code one time and the trigger will handle it for ever:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name
AFTER INSERT
   ON price FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   UPDATE Price SET Total = SUM(Units * Price_per_unit) where id=(select id from price order by id limit 1); 
END;
```

Comment: Thank you, I gues it needs to be trigger then... Well, maybe we can do another approach. So, as I understood, this trigger updates Total and not TOTAL. Right there is my actual problem. It's ok If I will be doing update manually, but I still need to do something with TOTAL.  When I do 
UPDATE Price SET Total = SUM(Units * Price_per_unit); it just sets sum for all rows, which is not what I need :(

Comment: Idea is, that I Do  Units * price from all rows and SUM it in 1 row. Hope you get my idea.

Comment: Ok! I updated the answer to limit the update query to first row. However I think this structure is not well formed and you have to separate the TOTAL field from this table.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I am actually learning for the test and I found out that this similar thing will be required. So yeah, It might be not well made structure for database, but I am not deciding what to do here. :/            So yeah, thank you very much.